# Add number to checkbox attributes and limit number of checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below table with checkboxes in it that will compare what is in each row up to a maximum of 3 items to compare.

So I am wanting some jQuery that will only allow 3 checkboxes to be selected, and then it will dynamically add a number to the end of the name attribute.

So if there were 2 to compare, the name attributes would be "horse_1" and "horse_2".

I have no clue where to start!

```
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2560092" name="horse_"></td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2560093" name="horse_"></td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2560094" name="horse_"></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="2560095" name="horse_"></td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Start by listening to the `change` event.

Comment: You want to restrict the UI that user can select any three check boxes  from the available check boxes.. Right..?

Comment: What happens when they click the forth? It doesn't get checked or should it cycle the selection by unselecting the first item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of selected elements using:

```
var selected = $('input:checked')
selected.length
```

If the number of selected elements is 3, you can disable all unchecked inputs. Here using the jQuery :not() selector to get the inverse of the :checked property.

```
    if (selected.length == 3) {
        $("input:not(:checked)").prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Then adding an else statement so that if 3 are not selected then no inputs are disabled.

```
    else {
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    }
```

You can then use an .each() to iterate over each of the checked elements to update their name, using the index of the element in the set as the number adding 1 to the value to counter the zero indexing:

```
    $('input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).attr('name', 'horse_' + (index + 1));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bj8L0ct2/1/